# Not able to remove "\t" from a text file using node.js

Tags: javascript

I aim to enhance the readability of a text file by eliminating the occurrence of "\t" (tab characters). Unfortunately, despite the code being error-free, it does not achieve the desired outcome. Now, you might wonder about the contents of the text file. Here is a snippet of the content for reference:

```
[{"name":"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\trandom name\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\temail  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\trandomnamet (per random), randomname@gmailcom (per studenti)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tphone  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t+0000000000\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t           \t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t            \t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"
```

I encountered a challenge while working on a task and sought a solution on Stack Overflow. Specifically, I attempted to address the following problem using Node.js:

I needed to remove the "\t" characters from a text file to improve its readability. Despite trying a few different approaches, I was unable to achieve the desired outcome. Here are the solutions I attempted:

1. Using the replace method:
   const cleanedData = data.replace(/\t/g, '');
   This approach aimed to replace all occurrences of "\t" with an empty string.
2. Utilizing a regular expression pattern to remove various whitespace characters:
   const cleanedData = data.replace(/[\t\n\r\s]/g, '');
   This pattern intended to remove "\t", newlines, carriage returns, and spaces from the data.

Additionally, I experimented with processing JSON data to extract names and emails, storing them in separate arrays. However, this code snippet doesn't directly relate to the main issue at hand.

Despite my attempts, the code did not produce the expected result. I'm now seeking guidance from the Stack Overflow community to identify any potential errors or alternative approaches that could help me remove the "\t" characters from the text file effectively.

Thank you in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash: `/\\t/g`

Comment: Even if you remove the `\t` and `\n` then it still doesn't look like valid JSON. I wouldn't remove the spaces though as they could be important.

Comment: @phuzi They say it's a "snippet" of the contents, not the complete JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using alternative methods to remove the tab characters. One approach is to split the data into an array of lines using data.split('\n') and then iterate over each line, replacing the tab characters with an empty string. Finally, join the lines back into a single string.

```
const lines = data.split('\n');
const cleanedData = lines.map(line => line.replace(/\t/g, '')).join('\n');
```